# '.class' expected. array method error

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
public class warm4{

  public static void main(String[] args){
     double scale = 3;
     double[] array = {1,2,3};
  }
    public static double[] scalarMultiply(double[] array, double scale){
      for( int i=0; i>array.length; i++){
      array[i] = (array[i])*scale;
      }
      return array[]; **//error here!**
     }
  }
```

I dont know how to correct that error!

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
  return array; **// Now no error here!**
```

No need for that extra `[]`.

`[]` is a syntax part of array declaration time to specify length of `array`.

So need to add that while returning that `array`. Just use variable name.

Answer (score 0):

`array[]` doesn't make sense.
If you want to return the value of a variable, just return that variable.